# Good heatsink for socket LGA 2011-v3?

Tags: gaming, heat-sink

I am going to be building a computer for a college student. He is going into general engineering while he figures out exactly what he wants to do. The budget for this computer is about $1500 USD (just for the tower). This computer will be running Windows 10. He will be using this computer for school work and for gaming.

From my previous [question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/239/60), it looks like I will be getting an [Intel i7 5820K Haswell](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819117402&cm_re=LGA2011-_-19-117-402-_-Product). The only problem is that it doesn't come with a heat sink. In my previous builds, the stock cooler was enough to get the job done.

As I will not be overclocking the system, air cooling should be enough. The heat sink must fit the LGA 2011-v3 socket. The case that all of this goes in will be no smaller than an ATX Mid case.

Since there are many options, I will try to narrow it down. I don't care about the noise level, as long as it doesn't sound like a jet engine. It should be more effective at cooling than the average heat sink. I am hoping that I can purchase one for less than $50.

Which heat sinks are worthy of a recommendation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever I hear "heatsink" I immediately think of the [Cooler Master Hyper 212 EVO](http://www.coolermaster.com/cooling/cpu-air-cooler/hyper-212-evo/) (~$30). I, along with tons of other people, will instantly recommend this over anything else. It's actually gained sort of a cult following for how great it is.

- Fits LGA 2011 sockets and many others
- 2x120mm fans (600-2000 RPM)
- 9-36dB — 9dB on the lowest setting is **insanely quiet**, 36dB is still great too
- Four pipes and the large number of aluminum fins directly remove heat for faster cooling
- Outstanding performance for pretty much any workload

And of course, temperature management is awesome for the price. [This graph](http://www.ocinside.de/media/uploads/cpu_cooler_compare_full_rpm.jpg) shows the 212 EVO's idle and load temperatures compared to others of the same capacity. It isn't the coolest heatsink on the market right now — you can get unimaginably cool ones now — but since heatsinks are, after all, all about temperature, price goes way up as temp goes down. The 212 EVO sits at above average in every category.

Comment: Although the 212 EVO is an awesome cooler, there are usually many alternatives at a similar price point: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-2467876/alternatives-hyper-212-evo-budget-cooling.html

Comment: @Alpha3031 There are absolutely lots of alternatives available. The 212 EVO is just a better bet than some of the others.

Comment: Warning: Check the height restrictions of your setup first as sometimes the heatsink size causes issues.

Comment: @Gram, OP hasn't picked a case yet, but it won't be too small, as apparently OP is opting for a ATX mid tower case.