# What are the smallest mini-ITX cases available?

Tags: case

I want to build a PC as small as possible, so I'm considering a mini-ITX build which support dedicated graphic card. In fact I don't need a graphic card right now, but just in case I will need one in the future, so mini-ITX seems to be a good choice.

I want a small and solid chassis at reasonable price, any recommends?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because cases don't fall within the hardware we can recommend.

Comment: Err....I see many questions about case like this one http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/561/computer-case-for-new-college-build?rq=1 In my personal opinion, case along with case fan are very important hardware as they almost determine the loudness of a PC.

Comment: That may be so, but it still doesn't fall within our scope. That question you linked is from the start of the life of the site, when cases were on topic; they're not any more.

Comment: Alright, got it. Please close my question.

Comment: Why has this been put on hold? It's a legitimate question - if we can't recommend cases what's the point of this site?

Comment: I nominate that this question be reopened once my pending edits are accepted. The question is now about integrated USB 3.0 circuitry, not cases.