# Should I get CPU cooler?

Tags: processor

I want to know if I need a CPU cooler for my build. I know I do, but is the one included with my i5 8600k enough? Just note that I am on LGA1151

1. ASRock Z370 PRO4 motherboard
2. Gigabyte GeForce GTX 1060 Windforce OC 3GB
3. Corsair Builder Series VS450, 450 Watt PSU

So my question is, is the CPU cooler included (if there is one I am not sure) with my CPU enough to support? Or should I get a different one?

Comment: I do not think that it will come with a heat sink. Do you have any other requirements, other than the socket it must support? Things like price and size are a good starting point. I also have a [related question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/294/60) that you might be interested in.

Comment: @Cfinley My bad I didn't mention that I have an LGA1151 socket so I can't use that one.

Comment: The [Hyper 212 EVO](http://www.coolermaster.com/cooling/cpu-air-cooler/hyper-212-evo/) does support the 1151 socket by the way. I bought 3 of them because of the question. One is on an Intel build, one is on an older AMD, and the last one is on an AM3+ build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It does not come with a cooler or thermal paste](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819117825). Since the point of a K skew CPU is overclocking, you'll want a beefy cooler so you can push your CPU to the max.

[Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/intel-coffee-lake-core-i5-8600k-cpu,5264-11.html) ran benchmarks, and it's clear that the 8600K eats a massive amount of power, especially when overclocked.

[image]

I'd recommend a cooler with at least a 105W TDP. The [Cryorig H7](http://a.co/3ovD3UJ) is rated for 140W and costs only $30, but any cooler that can handle the heat should do.

Comment: Just a question, would [this](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00JQ2YDCY/ref=psdc_11036281_t2_B007JEMXYQ) one meet what you said? I can't any TDP stats about it.

Comment: @TGamer Yes, it's rated for 130W, but it seems a tad pricy for a cooler from Deepcool.

Comment: Can u suggest a better one? I am looking for a blue LED one to suit my build.

Comment: If you need one with blue LEDs, that's the cheapest then. However, you could always buy something like an H7 and then put on your own fan, which would also let you use the one from an H7 elsewhere in your build.